# File Upload Issue In Channel Form

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads, safecracker-file, channel-files

I am running 2.9.3 using Channel Forms, the issue is if I try and upload a excel or .xlsx file it never uploads, even though eventually the form submits (it's considerable slower submit), no upload happens.

If I try .txt or an image file, it's fine. I have the enctype="multipart/form-data" in the tag, so not sure what might be occurring here. Any ideas, I have been at it for a while and not sure what it might be.

Comment: Try uploading the same file into the same folder via the file manager to confirm the file type is allowed & folder is writable.

Comment: I tried that and it's totally fine through the ACP, it's only via channel form it goes wonky.

Comment: Post up the relevant code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. You can solve it by disabling XSS filtering:

Admin -> Security and Privacy -> Security and Sessions. Than select "No" for "Apply XSS Filtering to uploaded files"

Comment: Excellent, that worked :) Thank you, very grateful!